# Mysql Error: trying to find columns in database

Tags: mysql

Im trying to insert user data into my mysql database but Im getting this error " sql: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE undefined = ?' "

Here is my code :

```
 find: function(user = null, callback) {

        //if the user variable is defined 
        if(user) {
            var field = Number.isInteger(user) ? 'id' : 'email';
       }
       // prepare the sql query
       let sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE ${field} = ?`;

        pool.query(sql, user, function(err, result){
                if(err) throw err;

                if(result.length){
                    callback(result[0]);
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Check why `$field` variable value is `'undefined'` instead of `id` or `email`... maybe this variable declaration must be moved out of `IF` statement?

Comment: This looks like application code

Comment: I fixed the code and im getting field to come as the condition its supposed to. However im getting an error still that says below. I guess maybe the string exists operator '?' is wrong

 sql: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?'